# Linux file uploads, fwrites, does not work

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, temporary-files

I have installed fedora15 on my system, installed apache and php5.3 and mysql. I have not changed any default setting in any configuration files

Created one ftpuser and uploaded files to Documentroot which is '/var/www/html/' and when I run php files all the files runs successfully.

But when it comes to file-uploads, fopen, fwrite, imagemagick convert etc all the programs which involve creation of files programatically does not work. I have given 777 permissions to the folder where I run the php scripts but still it gives me the access denied error.

Below is a sample code which creates permission denied error.

```
    $handle =   fopen("test.txt","w+");
    if(!$handle)die("Could not open file for writing");
    fwrite($handle,"Testing Uploads Successfull.");
    fclose($handle);
```

The above file is located in '/var/www/html/test/' directory of my newly installed fedora15 system.

Though if I run this file as a root user using php command line it executes correctly creating a new file and the text inside it. If I run the same file in command line with another user it produces permission denied error, though the directory has got 777 permission over it.

Please any one help me with this wierd behaiour,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be app-armor or se-linux?

Comment: thanks for your reply but can you elaborate it more, so as to know what I have to do.

Comment: it is a service to protect your system. i'm not user of fedore, but i remember that this could bring such problems. you can try to disable selinux for testing: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Comment: Maybe the problem is [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) enabled. But remember that (quotation from [php.net](http://php.net/)): *This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux is preventing the web server from creating and writing to files. See the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page for more details.

Comment: Thanks RomanKonz and Ignacio for guiding me in the right direction. The problem is solved now. It was an issue with the selinux only. It did not had httpd_write option enabled. Making httpd solved the issue.
Thanks a log once again.